# How to use instance?

Tags: haskell

Error message:

```
ho8.hs:17:19:
    Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraints:
      (PPLetter a0) arising from a use of `ppLetter' at ho8.hs:17:19-26
      (Num a0) arising from the literal `3' at ho8.hs:17:28
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the first argument of `print', namely `(ppLetter 3)'
    In the expression: print (ppLetter 3)
    In the expression: do { print (ppLetter 3) }
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Source code:

```
    module Main where
import Data.List(nub)

import qualified Text.PrettyPrint.HughesPJ as PP
import Text.PrettyPrint.HughesPJ(Doc,text,int,(<>),(<+>),($+$),render)

class PPLetter a where
 ppLetter :: a -> Doc

instance PPLetter Int where
 ppLetter a = text ("p"++show a)

instance PPLetter Char where
 ppLetter = PP.char


main = do {print (ppLetter 3);}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your updated question, replace

```
main = do {print (ppLetter 3);}
```

with

```
main = do {print (ppLetter (3 :: Int));}
```

Answer (score 4):

**show** is approximately :: a -> String

It turns a value into a String, but does not print it to screen.

**do** needs a IO action to actually print a String to screen, typically

```
putStr :: String -> IO ()
```

so try:

```
main = do { putStr (show (ppLetter 3)) }
```

More succinctly **print** combines the two:

```
main = do { print (ppLetter 3) }
```